# 2-Way databinding with Entity Framework and WPF DataGrid , is Possible?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, entity, frame

i am working on POS application  using SQL CE , WPF , Entity framework 3.5sp2  and iam   trying to use data grid as my Order Entry Control  for  User to enter  Products Order . 
 Iam plannning to bind this to enitiy frmae work model , abd looking for 2 way updating ?

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        using (MasterEntities nwEntities = new MasterEntities())
        {
          var users = from d in nwEntities.Companies
        select new CompanyRowModel{ CompanyId = d.CompanyId, CompanyName       d.CompanyName, Place = d.Place }

              listBox1.DataContext = users;
              dataGrid1.DataContext = users;
        }           
      }

      public class CompanyRowModel
      {
        public int CompanyId { get; set; }
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
        public string Place{ get; set; }
      }
```

and my xaml coding goes like this

```
   <Grid>
     <ListBox Name="listBox1" ItemsSource="{Binding}"  />
    <Button Content="Show "  Name="button1" Click="button1_Click"  />

    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="dataGrid1" ItemsSource="{Binding}" >
      <DataGrid.Columns>
          <DataGridTextColumn Header=" ID"     Binding="{Binding CompanyId}"/>
          <DataGridTextColumn Header="Company Name"  Binding="{Binding CompanyName}"/>
          <DataGridTextColumn Header="Place"    Binding="{Binding Place}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <Button Content="Save"  Name="button2" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Click="button2_Click" />
</Grid>
```

EDITED :

i  made the changes shown by @vorrtex,    But,  then i added another button to save the chages   and in button click event  i added follwing code   , butit showing   Updating error

```
  private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
         nwEntities.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Comment: Also there is another way: write just "var users = nwEntities.Companies.ToList()". But if a table has fields with a large size this solution will cause performance problems.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.

---

OK, after your edit(s)

You are now storing the selected property-values in a new, ad-hoc class CompanyDataRowModel.

That is not a tracked class. Either writer your own self-tracking entity classes or use the Company class.

Comment: but i/m getting an error while doing so  please help  ..see  Modified Question

Comment: i updated my wuetion with specific example can you help me ?

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem with this code:

```
select new { d.CompanyId, d.CompanyName, d.Place }
```

Properties in this anonymous class are read-only, so you should create a real class with these properties.

```
public class CompanyRowModel
{
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    //...
}
//...
var users = from d in nwEntities.Companies
            select new CompanyRowModel{ CompanyId = d.CompanyId, CompanyName = d.CompanyName, Place = d.Place }
```

Comment: i  changed my coding as you shown and got a new error on saving the entity , can you help me ?

Comment: You have made changes in a CLR-object, not entity. Synchronize the object collection with the entity collection. For example, use an event RowEditEnding and copy values of a CompanyRowModel object to a related entity in the nwEntities.Companies. They are related by ID so be sure that this column is read-only in the DataGrid.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in the **BookLibrary** sample application of the **[WPF Application Framework (WAF)](http://waf.codeplex.com)**. It uses the Entity Framework also with SQL CE as DB and it contains the WPF DataGrid.